# Sprite buttons on the HUD do not detect a touch event if the ZoomCamera moves from its original position

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to place some clickable sprites on the HUD of my ZoomCamera.
The sprites detect the touch event just fine, but only if the ZoomCamera is placed in its original position.

If I zoom in, or pan the camera, it seems like the touch areas remain in their area relative to the scene, and not to the camera. Therefore the action only works if I click on the area where the sprites existed in the original state.

This is most of the relevant code -

```
FloorSelectorButton firstButton = new FloorSelectorButton(0, 100, 80, 80,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), 3, this);

    FloorSelectorButton secondButton = new FloorSelectorButton(0, 180, 80, 80,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), 2, this);

    FloorSelectorButton thirdButton = new FloorSelectorButton(0, 260, 80, 80,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), 1, this);


    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.setOnAreaTouchTraversalFrontToBack();
    HUD hud = new HUD();

    mZoomCamera.setHUD(hud);

    hud.attachChild(firstButton);
    hud.attachChild(secondButton);
    hud.attachChild(thirdButton);

    hud.registerTouchArea(firstButton);
    hud.registerTouchArea(secondButton);
    hud.registerTouchArea(thirdButton);
            this.mScrollDetector = new SurfaceScrollDetector(this);
        this.mPinchZoomDetector = new PinchZoomDetector(this);
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
        this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
        return mScene;
```

FloorSelectorButton is just a class that extends Sprite and implements the onAreaTouch method.

I hope you guys could help my out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently my problem was really dumb. It seems that for some reason the APK wasn't updated on the phone and it stayed with the old code (because of this - http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2eb92316b474fa00)  where I set the registerTouchArea on the scene instead of the HUD.

So now it's fixed! :)

Thanks anyways!

Comment: That is correct, this is a common mistake of newbie AndEngine developers such as myself. Therefore, BEWARE everyone, make sure you set your TouchAreas on the correct Scene!